# QuarkusTest with an ApplicationScoped bean and AfterEach-Callback

Tags: java, junit5, quarkus

I'm writing a simple QuarkusTest for a bean that is marked as `ApplicationScoped` and very simple:

```
package com.foo.bar;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBean {

    String postConstructInitializedVariable;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        postConstructInitializedVariable = "foo";
    }

    public int getVariableLength() {
        return postConstructInitializedVariable.length();
    }
}
```

The test looks like this:

```
package com.foo.bar;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@QuarkusTest
class MyBeanTest {

    @Inject
    MyBean myBean;


    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println(myBean.postConstructInitializedVariable.length());
    }


    @Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals(3, myBean.getVariableLength());
    }
}
```

The test fails with a NPE in the tearDown() method - postConstructInitializedVariable is null.
I found [this in the docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#enrichment-via-quarkustestcallback) but then I'm wondering how to properly execute code after each test to reset some of my test resources.
What's interesting to me: Replacing @ApplicationScoped with @Singleton fixes the problem.

Any advice on this?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way the `@ApplicationScoped` bean is bootstrapped by Quarkus somehow creates a proxy method of the PostConstruct annotated method. If you actually add a logging/System.out line in the `postConstruct()` method, you will see that this method is called once only when one of the bean's public methods are invoked for the first time. Thereafter, the `postConstruct()` method is not called again, which is how it is expected to work